# java ternary operator

Tags: java, ternary-operator

Can someone explain why this code?

```
Collection c = (5 == 5) ? new ArrayList() : new HashSet();
```

produces the following compiler error:

> Incompatible conditional operand types ArrayList and HashSet

For reasons that I don't understand, the following fixes the problem

```
Collection c = (5 == 5) ? (Collection) new ArrayList() : new HashSet();
```

I'm using Java 1.4.

Comment: Note that the first compiles fine on Java 1.5 and up.

Comment: Works fine on my machine running Sun's JDK version 1.6.0_16

Comment: Off the point, but worth asking - It looks like `5 == 5` doesn't appear strange to anyone else but me. As far as I understand, `c` will always evaluate to `new ArrayList()`. Can anyone explain why it might be useful to do `Collection c = (5 == 5) ? new ArrayList() : new HashSet();` instead of simply doing `Collection c = new ArrayList();` considering that `(5 == 5)` always evaluates to `true`?

Comment: @SultanBaby there is no practical reason why you would write code like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a **bug** in 1.4 and has been fixed according [bugreport 5080917](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5080917).

> **Evaluation** This is a bug.
>
> xxxxx@xxxxx   2004-07-30

Comment: +1 You are right. I misread the spec, and delete my answer now.

Comment: That's a bug in 1.5 (tiger) fixed in 1.6 (mustang). It looks like a specific instance of the rule introduced in 1.5/3rd Ed JLS.

Comment: @Daniel I think your answer was almost there.

Comment: @Tom / @Daniel: I think *both* answers were after all correct. The new rules were introduced for 1.5 but there were bugs. Daniel however already got five upvotes for the 1st paragraph without pointing the 1.4/1.5 differences in any way before he copypasted some JLS cites (which I only saw after posting my answer).

Comment: There's always lots of bugs. The cited bug is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Daniel more or less gets this right, but has deleted his answer (with five up votes).

Relevant quote from 2nd Ed JLS (1.2-1.4)

> - If the second and third operands are
>     of different reference types, then it 
>     must be possible to convert one of 
>     the types to the other type (call 
>     this latter type T) by assignment
>     conversion (§5.2); the type of the
>     conditional expression is T. It is a
>     compile-time error if neither type is
>     assignment compatible with the other
>     type.

One of the types needs to be convertible to the other, which is not true of `ArrayList` and `HashSet` but is true of `Collection` and `HashSet` and of `ArrayList` and `Collection`.

In 3rd Ed JLS (1.5+)

> - Otherwise, the second and third
>     operands are of types S1 and S2
>     respectively. Let T1 be the type that
>     results from applying boxing
>     conversion to S1, and let T2 be the
>     type that results from applying
>     boxing conversion to S2. The type of
>     the conditional expression is the
>     result of applying capture conversion
>     (§5.1.10) to lub(T1, T2)
>     (§15.12.2.7).

This does the obvious thing, which as it turns out is more difficult to specify and implement (I unintentionally got an early version of javac to crash on it when one of the expressions was `void`). IIRC, this was work done as part of generics.