# java code formats

Tags: java

I'm really sorry for what must be a really stupid question. I don't exactly have formal training in java and a lot of times, when looking through code, I might see something like:

```
(  ) ?   :
```

as in something like:

```
for (str == null) ? getString(this) : dontGetit(nope.this);
```

honestly i don't even know exactly it is or if it's remotely close, but hopefully one could recognize the scheme. I was hoping one could perhaps link some documentation on this because i have trouble even searching for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ternary operator in Java. Read here : http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/oper/ternary.html

Answer (score 2):

it an **ternary operator** used to evaluate **boolean expressions**. It is equivalent to if-else statement.

**Syntax:**

```
   variable_name= (boolean expression) ? value to assign if true : value to assign if false
```

**using terenary operator:**

```
    boolean isHappy = true;
    String mood = (isHappy == true)?"I'm Happy!":"I'm Sad!";
```

**using if-else:**

```
 if(isHappy) {
     mood="I'm Happy";
  }
  else {
     mood = "I'm, Sad!";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

this is conditional or ternary operator in java

```
( a ) ? b  : c;
```

if `a` is true `b` will be executed or run

if `a` is false `c` will be executed or run

Answer (score 1):

It's the ternary operator . It's good in sets, and a shortcut for iteration

[java ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181217/java-ternary-operator)

Here's an easy ex.:

```
boolean isObese = true;

 String mood = (isObese == true)?"I need to quit fast-food!":"I'm healthy!";
```

[..source](http://java.about.com/b/2009/06/06/java-term-of-the-week-ternary-operator.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It's called ternary operator, it can be allocated to a variable and it is equivalent of an if-then-else statement.

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) and pay attention on something that hasn't been underlined enough by the other answers: the fact that the ternary operator *is an expression that can be allocated to a variable or can be returned directly by a method*. It has a functional feel into it.